# "Cannot call method 'oEmbed' of null" when embedding Soundcloud player in dynamically generated Div

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Using the Soundcloud JavaScript API, I want to dynamically generate a page of player widgets using track search results.  My code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>

<script>
function makeDivsFromTracks(tracks,SC)
{
 var track;
 var permUrl;
 var newDiv;
 for(var ctr=0;ctr<tracks.length;ctr++)
 {
  newDiv=document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id="track"+ctr;
  track=tracks[ctr];
  SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url,{color:"ff0066"},newDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
 }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});
SC.get('/tracks',{duration:{to:900000},tags:'hitech',downloadable:true},
        function(tracks,SC)
        {
         makeDivsFromTracks(tracks,SC);
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I load this, the `SC.oEmbed()` call throws an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'oEmbed' of null
```

which would seem to indicate that either the `div`s aren't being generated or the search results aren't being returned, but if I remove the `SC.oEmbed()` call and replace it with:

```
newDiv.innerHTML=track.permalink_url;
```

then I get a nice list of the URLs for my search results.

And if I create a widget using a static `div` and static URL, e.g.

```
<body>
<div id="putTheWidgetHere"></div>
<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});
SC.oEmbed("http://soundcloud.com/exampleTrack", {color: "ff0066"},  document.getElementById("putTheWidgetHere"));
</script>
</body>
```

then that works fine as well.  So what's the problem with my `oEmbed()` call with these dynamically created elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.  I took out the `SC` argument from the callback function and `makeDivsFromTracks()`, and now all the players show up.  Not sure exactly why this works--maybe it has to do with the SC object being defined in the SDK script reference, so it's globally available and doesn't need to be passed into functions?

Anyways, working code is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>

<script>
function makeDivsFromTracks(tracks)
{
 var track;
 var permUrl;
 var newDiv;
 for(var ctr=0;ctr<tracks.length;ctr++)
 {
  newDiv=document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.id="track"+ctr;
  track=tracks[ctr];
  //newDiv.innerHTML=track.permalink_url;
  SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url,{color:"ff0066"},newDiv);
  document.body.appendChild(newDiv);

 }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});
SC.get('/tracks',{duration:{from:180000,to:900000},tags:'hitech',downloadable:true},function

(tracks){makeDivsFromTracks(tracks);});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how append the SC.oEmbed player to ul>li using appendTo?