# Is there a maximum number of player widgets that can be added to a web page?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm working on a project to add Soundcloud player widgets to a page based on search results (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355384/cannot-call-method-oembed-of-null-when-embedding-soundcloud-player-in-dynami)).  I'm able to successfully add the players, but if I add more than 3 to the page, they're not "playable"--I can't click on the play button and stream the music.  Is there an upper limit on the number of working widgets I'm allowed to add to a page?

code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>

<script>
function makeDivsFromTracks(tracks)
{
 var track;
 var permUrl;
 var newDiv;



 for(var ctr=0;ctr<tracks.length;ctr++)
 {
   track=tracks[ctr];

   if(track["downloadable"])
   {
   newDiv=document.createElement("div");
   newDiv.id="track"+ctr
   SC.oEmbed(track.permalink_url,{color:"ff0066"},newDiv);
   document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
   }
 }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<script>
SC.initialize({
    client_id: '9a81d4ed26119b89bc329700efef5ff2'
});
SC.get('/tracks',{duration:{from:180000,to:900000},tags:'hard trance'},function(tracks){makeDivsFromTracks(tracks);});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Added an example in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyvbD/1/

Comment: can you add some example on jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Pheonix, code and jsfiddle added.

Comment: hey the tracks are working for me on jsfiddle page!! I tested on Chrome Linux. and Firefox. The  listing comes bit messed up with blank spaces in firefox but it is playable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reply your question, there aren't limits on our side for amount of widgets on your page. However be aware many widgets might slow down your page – they are iframes with quite rich content.

Comment: yes, it looks like they are loading--just more slowly than expected.